# Cant submit more then one form in database from Angular because of duplicate primary key

Tags: angular, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, frontend, backend

So im building and application with Angular and WebAPI (Swagger) and i can only submit **once** (so when i try to submit it first time everything goes okay) my form into database otherwise i need to change my Id key in model class(class TimelyTable) by hand or it shows error 500 (that Primary Key is duplicate) so im guessing the problem should be in my WebApi Controller.
Im gussing I should have some function that increments my Id or something like that?

This is my model class in Angular:

```
    export class TimelyTable {
    id:number = 1;
    projectName:string = '';
    startTime:Date = new Date();
    stopTime:Date = new Date();
    duration:number = 0;
}
```

This is my form in html:

```
 <form  style="text-align: center;" #form="ngForm" (submit)="onButtonClick(form)">
        <input type="hidden" ngModel name="id" [value]="service.formData.id">
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 70px;">
            <label style="margin: 10px;">Project Name</label>
            <input class="form-contorl form-control-lg" placeholder="Project Name"
            ngModel name="projectName" #projectName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.projectName">
            <div>
                <label style="margin: 22px;">Start Time</label>
                <input class="form-contorl form-control-lg" placeholder="Start Time"
                ngModel name="startTime" #startTime="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.startTime">
            </div>
    <div>
        <label style="margin: 22px;">Stop Time</label>
        <input class="form-contorl form-control-lg" placeholder="Stop time"
        ngModel name="stopTime" #stopTime="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.stopTime">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label style="margin: 28px;">Duration</label>
        <input class="form-contorl form-control-lg" placeholder="duration"
        ngModel name="duration" #stopTime="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.duration">
    </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button  class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" style="margin-top: 40px; margin-right: 120px;">Start Time</button>
            <button  class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" style="margin-top: 40px;">Stop Time</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

This is my component file:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs';
import { TimelyTable } from 'src/app/shared/timely-table.model';
import { TimelyTableService } from 'src/app/shared/timely-table.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-form',
  templateUrl: './table-form.component.html'
})
export class TableFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public service:TimelyTableService){
  }
  formData = new TimelyTable();

  ngOnInit(): void {
  };


  onButtonClick(form:NgForm){
      this.service.postForm().subscribe(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result);
          this.resetform(form);
        }
        
      );
    }
  resetform(form:NgForm){
      form.form.reset();
      this.service.formData = new TimelyTable();
  }

}
```

And this is my service file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TimelyTable } from './timely-table.model';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/catchError';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TimelyTableService {
  httpOptions = {
    headers : ({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    }

  readonly APIUrl = environment.apiHost
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  formData:TimelyTable = new TimelyTable();

  postForm(){
   return this.http.post(`${this.APIUrl}`,this.formData);
  }
}
```

And my WebApi Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Time>> PostTime(Time time)
{
  _context.Times.Add(time);
  _context.Database.OpenConnection();
  try
  {
    _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Times ON;");
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Times OFF;");
  }
  finally
  {
    _context.Database.CloseConnection();
  }
  return CreatedAtAction("GetTime", new { id = time.Id }, time);
}
```

Comment: Please avoid social-media-like language. Pay attention to spelling, interpunction, proper capitalization, and style.

Comment: That said, you did a great job trying to post all relevant code, but most of the client-side code isn't really relevant. It would be relevant to see the `PostTime` class and the way it's mapped. The only thing that goes wrong here is that EF doesn't know the primary key is an identity column. You shouldn't need this `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowing the database to set the primary key, you should pass NULL for this value on all inserts (`SET IDENTITY_INSERT`).

Change the id value:

`id:number | unknown;`

You can also remove the hidden field:

`<input type="hidden" ngModel name="id" [value]="service.formData.id">`

This will need to be modified if you want your form to support edits (UPDATE/PUTs) but that is the idea for INSERT (POST).  You are defaulting the value to 1, hence a duplicate primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I made such a careless mistake. My GetTime() method was commented out in my WebApi Controller and that was the problem.